# How to map from csv file to another one in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 csv files . The first one looks like this :

```
ID , Exersice 
1 , 1.1
1 , 1.2
3 , 1.4
.
.
```

it simply contains the IDs of students and exercises they had done .
the second one contains the IDs and the grade of each one   :

```
ID , 1.1 , 1.2 ,1.3 ...
1  , 5   , 9   ,8   ...
3  , 4   , 10  ,6   ...
.
.
```

so how to map from the second file to the first one to be like this   :

```
ID , Exercise , grade 
1  , 1.1      , 5
1  , 1.2      , 9
.
.
```

Comment: It helps if you show what attempts you have tried until now. And how you would like the code to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Merge, join and concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

The link provides examples on how to do this

specific `pd.concat(data, axis=1)` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Create `MultiIndex Series` with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), if necessary convert all columns without first to floats and last use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
s = df2.set_index('ID').rename(columns=float).stack().rename('grade')
df = df1.join(s, on=['ID','Exersice'])
print (df)
   ID  Exersice  grade
0   1       1.1    5.0
1   1       1.2    9.0
2   3       1.4    NaN
```

Another similar solution:

```
df3 = df2.melt('ID', var_name='Exersice', value_name='new')
df3['Exersice'] = df3['Exersice'].astype(float)

df = df1.merge(df3, on=['ID','Exersice'], how='left')
print (df)
   ID  Exersice  new
0   1       1.1  5.0
1   1       1.2  9.0
2   3       1.4  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create the `grades` column to the first data frame by mapping values from the second table.

Here the `ID` column of the second table is set to index for easier mapping. Also, second table column values are strings, so while applying the cell values from the first are cast to strings.

```py
import pandas as pd

df_exercises = pd.read_csv("student_exercises.csv")
df_grades = pd.read_csv("student_grade.csv")

df_grades.set_index("ID", inplace=True)
df_exercises['grades'] = df_exercises.apply(lambda x: df_grades.loc[x.ID, str(x.Exersice)], axis=1)
```